# Using VBA: double clicking cell creates new sheet, cell is also hyperlinked to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Alright, so I am brand new at this. New role at work. I received this excel request:

1. Double clicking any cell in a sheet creates a new sheet.
2. Original cell that is double clicked now turns into a hyperlink, linking to the newly created sheet.
3. The double click function for this cell that was originally double click is removed.

I'm honestly stuck. I've not really programmed using VBA before. I've figured out how to create a new sheet upon double click, and I've figured out how to hyperlink. But I can't figure out how to hyperlink to a newly created sheet, and to remove the double click function from that original cell!

Here's all I have...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     Sheets.Add
End Sub
```

Also, forgive me if I'm breaking any rules here, this is my first time posting here. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'll give a +1 for good first question.  You've showed what you've tried/what you have, explained the problem and what the expected result is.  Hyperlinking can be tricky sometimes.  There's a lot of first questions with a lot less or just asking 'do this for me'.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I am looking forward to learning more, and getting better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right pathway, just need a few more components.  A key point is to declare and use object variables (`ws` in this case)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Prevent screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Add worksheet
    Set ws = Me.Parent.Worksheets.Add

    ' Add Hyperlink
    Target.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.Cells(1, 1).Address(True, True, , True), TextToDisplay:=ws.Name & "!A1"

    ' Restore original sheet as active
    Me.Activate

    ' Disable original Doubleclick action
    Cancel = True

    ' Restore screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A great resource for things Excel (aside from SO) is [cPearson.Com](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that is one hefty site -- I will bookmark it and reference it before I post again :). Thanks for the solution, I will test it shortly!

Comment: woops, put an extra comment sorry. It worked! I only removed: ", TextToDisplay:=ws.Name & "!A1" ", so the original text in the cell remains!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     Sheets.Add
End Sub
```

I'd like this simple code, can you make create new sheet from specific cell with look up from another sheet.